# Add custom image UIButtons to a custom UIToolbar does not work right

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uitoolbar, programmatically-created

I have implemented a custom `UIToolBar`  with 4 `UIbutton`'s. These buttons are button with Image. I have created them with this code:

```
-(NSArray *)setButtonForToolBar
{
    CGRect buttonFrame = {
        .origin.x = 0,
        .origin.y = 0,
        .size.width = self.frame.size.width/4,
        .size.height = self.frame.size.height,
    };
    
    NSLog(@"Frame width: %f  and Origin x: %f ", buttonFrame.size.width, buttonFrame.origin.x );
    // BOTON CHECK IN
    UIButton *checkinButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame] ;
    [checkinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkInService:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [checkinButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-checkin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkinButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-checkin-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    checkinButton.tag = 0;
    UIBarButtonItem *checkInBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: checkinButton];
    

    // BOTON PARA LA INFO
    buttonFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(buttonFrame);
NSLog(@"Frame width: %f  and Origin x: %f ", buttonFrame.size.width, buttonFrame.origin.x );
    UIButton *infoBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [infoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkInService:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [infoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-info.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-info-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    infoBtn.tag = 1;
    
    UIBarButtonItem *infoBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: infoBtn];
    
    
    // BOTON PARA VALORACIONES
     buttonFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(buttonFrame);
  NSLog(@"Frame width: %f  and Origin x: %f ", buttonFrame.size.width, buttonFrame.origin.x );
    UIButton *voteBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [voteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkInService:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [voteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-comment.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [voteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-comment-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    voteBtn.tag = 2;
    UIBarButtonItem *voteBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: voteBtn];
    
    
    // BOTON PARA PLANES
     buttonFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(buttonFrame);
           NSLog(@"Frame width: %f  and Origin x: %f ", buttonFrame.size.width, buttonFrame.origin.x );
    UIButton *planBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    [planBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkInService:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [planBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-fav.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [planBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-fav-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
    planBtn.tag = 3;
    
    UIBarButtonItem *planBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: planBtn];
    
    
    
    
    NSArray *buttonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:checkInBarBtn, infoBarBtn, voteBarBtn, planBarBtn, nil];
    return buttonItems;
}
```

`ToolBar` is created with a frame of = (10,400,300,60).

Look the `NSlog` Outputs :

```
2013-11-21 17:43:18.557 Woowplanet[3316:70b] Frame width: 75.000000  and Origin x: 0.000000 
2013-11-21 17:43:18.569 Woowplanet[3316:70b] Frame width: 75.000000  and Origin x: 75.000000 
2013-11-21 17:43:18.570 Woowplanet[3316:70b] Frame width: 75.000000  and Origin x: 150.000000 
2013-11-21 17:43:18.571 Woowplanet[3316:70b] Frame width: 75.000000  and Origin x: 225.000000
```

The output shows that they should be in the correct place, I do not know why they are almost 10 ponts to its right..

The problem is that buttons are not in the correct place. Look at the picture[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

create bar button with flexible space

```
 UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

And do this:

```
NSArray *buttonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,checkInBarBtn,flexibleSpace, infoBarBtn,flexibleSpace, voteBarBtn,flexibleSpace, planBarBtn,flexibleSpace, nil];
```